# How to add some data from BASH variables to the beginning of all lines in a CSV file?

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

I need to add `$author \t $title \t` to the beginning of every line in a tab-seperated CSV file. This is an example of what the file looks like originally:

```
0001      This is a line.
0002      This is another line.
0003      This is yet another line.
```

After editing, and assuming `$author` is set to "Lewis Carroll" and `$title` set to "Through the Looking Glass", the output would look just like this:

```
Lewis Caroll      Through the Looking Glass      0001      This is a line.
Lewis Caroll      Through the Looking Glass      0002      This is another line.
Lewis Caroll      Through the Looking Glass      0003      This is yet another line.
```

I tried the following attempts with `awk`, but it does not work as expected, and `$author` and `$title` do not appear to be added anywhere in the file:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ print "$author\t$title\t" $0 }' file.txt

awk -F"\t" '{ print $author \t $title \t $0 }' file.txt
```

How can I add some data, containing BASH variables, as cells, to the beginning of all of the lines in a tab-seperated CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you're doing, but it should work:

```
awk -vauthor="Lewis Carrol" -vtitle="Through the Looking Glass" '{print author, title, $0 }' OFS='\t' inputfile
```

<sub>Were you attempting to pass shell variables instead?</sub>

---

For the case at hand, you are better off using `sed`, though:

```
sed "s/^/${author}\t${title}\t/" filename
```

(Remember to use double quotes)

Comment: Yes, the `$author` is retrieved from elsewhere `author="$(echo $line | awk -F@ '{print $2}')"` earlier in the script.

Comment: @Village You need to pass variables to `awk`.  If it's a shell variable, say: `-vauthor="$author" -v title="$title"`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/^/${author}\t${title}\t/" file.txt
```

You can also add `-i` option to sed for in-place update

```
sed -i "s/^/${author}\t${title}\t/" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
author="Lewis Carrol" 
title="Through the Looking Glass" 
while read -r line
do
  printf "${author}\t${title}\t${line}\n"
done < file
```